# Make JWPlayer fit the screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, frame, jwplayer

I added JWPlayerController to the UIView.
Using
_jwConfig.size = CGSizeMake(400, 400);
the video is moving out of the screen. I wouldn't want to hard-code values in CGSizeMake because it will be played on variety of devices.
[image: Image does not fit the screen]

However, when I double click on the controller, the player enters the full screen and if I click somewhere on the screen I will see the duration slider as well.
[image: Full screen mode]

How do I make JWPlayer fit the screen without going into full screen mode?

Comment: try `_jwConfig.size = self.view.frame.size`

Comment: Hey - This does fit the screen but upon one click I am unable to see the duration slider. I have to double click to put the player in full screen mode and then I can see the slider.

Comment: you need to consult JWPlayer docs for that. can you point me to its docs

Comment: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/configuration-reference/ In Appearance section, stretching field is given. But I am unable to use it in my present code.

Comment: https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/ios/docs/developer-guide/embedding/embedding/ this shows that the control property is set to `YES` by default

Comment: How is my question related to controls?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123781/discussion-between-shubhank-and-astha-gupta).

Comment: did you solved it yet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added UIView in storyboard and set various constraints like trailing, leading from main view. setup player:

```
_jwConfig = [[JWConfig alloc] init];
[self setContentUrl];
_jwConfig.size = self.jwPlayerView.frame.size;
self.jwConfig.controls = YES;
self.jwConfig.repeat = NO;
self.jwConfig.premiumSkin = JWPremiumSkinBeelden;
self.jwConfig.offlineMessage = kZErNoInternet;
self.jwPlayer = [[JWPlayerController alloc] initWithConfig:_jwConfig];
self.jwPlayer.delegate = self;
[self.jwPlayerView addSubview:self.jwPlayer.view];

- (void) onReady {
    self.jwPlayer.view.frame = self.jwPlayerView.frame;
}
```

This solved my problem.

Additionally, there is a problem with the new XCode. The frame size by default is taken as 1000, 1000, because of which the self.jwPlayerView.frame.size; wasn't giving the correct size. You need to use 'layoutIfNeeded' method to get the correct size. I defined the frame in 'onReady' method though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building this in a native iOS app, using the iOS SDK (rather than the web player) should solve your issue by default: https://developer.jwplayer.com/ios-sdk/